# invalid product key windows 7

Tags: windows-7, product-key

When I open computer properties and scroll to bottom, I saw that Windows activation told me that I have to activate my Windows, and changing the product key.

It only given me 3 options for activation, "buy new product key online", "type a different product key", "Contact Microsoft to help resolve this problem".

Contact Microsoft option only popup "Windows help and support", but "buy new product key online" doesn't redirect me to anything related to Windows 7, but Windows 10, here's the link (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/upgrade-faq-windows-10?p=&lcid=17417&req=XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX&OSV=6.1.7601.2.00010100.1.0.001.09.1033&LS=1&LegitCheckError=00000052&GenuineInfo=4004F00C&Channel=8&ErrCode=4004F00C I have replaced my product key with XXXXX, the product key is OEM)

The problem now is that I don't have the product key. But before August 1st, it display "Genuine Windows" logo on the computer properties.

Is it only me had this problem, that there's something wrong with my computer?

Comment: The link you have given is for upgrading to Windows 10.

Comment: @albal it redirect me to that website